# Understanding plus and minus zero

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, limits

Why is right limit as x goes to 1 of $e^{1/(x^2-1)} = e^{1/(+0)} = \infty$

And the left limit as x goes to 1 of $e^{1/(x^2-1)} = e^{1/(-0)} = 0$

I do not really understand what +0 and -0 actually means and how in the upper example can we see what sign it will have from left or right. I understand the second part that $e^{\infty} = \infty$ and that $e^{-\infty} = 0$, but the first part really doesn't make sense to me, how can we know what kind of sign the zero will have?

Can somebody explain how can we see from limits if there is plus zero or minus zero in the result. (you can use the upper example for your explanation)

Comment: There is no such thing as plus and minus zero.

Comment: @JohnDouma there is in programming. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero)

Comment: The point here should be that we are *not* actually "plugging in zero"... we are looking at the *limit* as numbers *approach* zero from the right or from the left.  When $x$ is greater than $1$ you have $x^2-1$ is positive.  When $x$ is less than (*but still near*) $1$ you have $x^2-1$ is negative.  $1$ divided by a small *but positive* number will result in a *large* positive number.  $1$ divided by a small *but negative* number will result in a *large* negative number.

Comment: @JMoravitz That points to a shortcoming in one's complement representation. Zero is the additive identity. There is only one.

Comment: @AndreasBlass You're quite right. Objection withdrawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, $e^{1/(+0)}$ is just a short way of writing $\lim_{x\to0^+}e^{1/x}$, which is $\infty$. And $e^{1/(-0)}$ is just a short way of writing $\lim_{x\to0^-}e^{1/x}(=0)$.

Comment: Thaank you, I didnt know we could write it like this. I have another question, in the example of $e^{1/(x^2-1)}$ goes to $1$ let's say from the left. How do I know that this limit from the left to $1$ will produce $\frac{1}{1-1} = \frac{1}{-0}$. And not $+0$ in the denominator.

Comment: If $x$ goes to $1$ from the left, then $x^2<1$ when $x$ is close enough to $1$, and therefore $x^2-1<0$. So, its $1/(-0)$ here.

Comment: I see, so we could actually say that we get $\frac{1}{(1-\epsilon)-1}$ And $\epsilon>0$, thus the value on the bottom will be very close to zero, but from the negative side. Do I understand correctly ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @BiliDebili yes, though you may want to be more strict with how you write that... it would be better written as $(1-\epsilon)^2-1$ for the denominator, which you can still show is close to zero but from the negative side.  The point being that there will be some cases where you do not go negative from the right or from the left, for instance $\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: @JMoravitz $\frac{1}{x^2}$ the left limit to 0 would be: $\frac{1}{(-0)^2}=\frac{1}{+0} = + \infty$ is the same as the limit from the right. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @JMoravitz Or if I would write it with $(0-\epsilon)^2 = (\epsilon)^2$ for $\epsilon >0$, thus the above holds.